# Python SQLite to insert list with variable number of entries

Tags: python, sqlite, insert

I've got a web scraper that pulls data down from a site and puts it in various lists for insertion into a SQLite database.  I've started pulling new data today but the problem is, unlike the previous data, I could have anywhere from 0 to 15 entries of a certain type.  It's a perk applied to a card - each perk has a name and a description of what that perk does.

I've gotten to the point where I have all the data in a list ready to insert but I don't know how to make the insert statement dynamic to where it writes the statement with the correct column names (quirk# where # is a number from 1-15, quirk_desc# where # is a number from 1 to 15) and with the correct data.

I know about using executemany and using question marks and the list itself and I'm doing that in other inserts where the columns needed and the data are static.

Is there someway to read the max column count of that line of the list and use a variable to write the column names out using the correct number?  Can I name the columns in my list and have the insert statement pull the column names as the column names in the insert statement?

The list in question is quirk_data_final.  I didn't put my SQLite connection info or anything in the code.

Code starts by pulling a list of players for each team and compiles that into a list of links.  It then iterates through that list, pulling the required data depending on the type of player.

Per request - database definitions:

> CREATE TABLE "Quirk" (
>       "Player"    TEXT,
>       "Link"  TEXT,
>       "Overall"   INTEGER,
>       "Team"  TEXT,
>       "Quirk 1" TEXT,
>       "Quirk 1 Description" TEXT,
>       "Quirk 2" TEXT,
>       "Quirk 2 Description" TEXT,
>       "Quirk 3" TEXT,
>       "Quirk 3 Description" TEXT,
>       "Quirk 4" TEXT,
>       "Quirk 4 Description" TEXT,
>       "Quirk 5" TEXT,
>       "Quirk 5 Description" TEXT,
>       "Quirk 6" TEXT,
>       "Quirk 6 Description" TEXT,
>       "Quirk 7" TEXT,
>       "Quirk 7 Description" TEXT,
>       "Quirk 8" TEXT,
>       "Quirk 8 Description" TEXT,
>       "Quirk 9" TEXT,
>       "Quirk 9 Description" TEXT,
>       "Quirk 10" TEXT,
>       "Quirk 10 Description" TEXT,
>       "Quirk 11" TEXT,
>       "Quirk 11 Description" TEXT,
>       "Quirk 12" TEXT,
>       "Quirk 12 Description" TEXT,
>       "Quirk 13" TEXT,
>       "Quirk 13 Description" TEXT,
>       "Quirk 14" TEXT,
>       "Quirk 14 Description" TEXT,
>       "Quirk 15" TEXT,
>       "Quirk 15 Description" TEXT,
>       "Pull_Date_Time"    NUMERIC
>   )

Code for the full app:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
import sqlite3

fp = (r'C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\ceo61d4m.default')
opts = Options()
opts.profile = fp
opts.headless = True
options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
path = r'C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\ceo61d4m.default'
options.add_argument("user-data-dir="+path)
quote_page = ('https://mlb19.theshownation.com/inventory?type=players&optional_id=2')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Users\USER\.spyder-py3\geckodriver.exe', firefox_options = opts)
driver.get(quote_page)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "lxml")

all_player_data_P = []
all_player_data_NoP = []
all_player_quirk_data = []
quirk_data_final = []

def pull_player(url2):
    global all_player_data_P
    global all_player_data_NoP
    global quirk_data_final
    stats_data = []
    general_data = []
    pitching_data = []
    pitch_speeds = []
    driver.get(url2)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "lxml")
    span = soup.find('div', class_='card-asset')
    Last = span.find('div', class_='card-name-last').string
    First = span.find('div', class_='card-name-first').string
    try:
        Player = First+' '+Last
    except TypeError:
        Player = First
    Link = url2
    Team = span.find('div', class_='card-team').string
    span2 = soup.find('div', class_='widget-main title-widget-main')
    General = span2.find('h1').getText()
    list = General.split()
    Position = list[0]
    Number = list[1]
    rows = span2.find_all('div', class_='flex-table-cell')
    for each in rows:
        general_data.append(each.text.strip().encode('utf-8'))
    Overall = general_data[0].decode("utf-8") 
    Bats = general_data[1].decode("utf-8") 
    Throws = general_data[2].decode("utf-8") 
    Secondary = general_data[3].decode("utf-8")
    Secondary2 = str(Secondary)
    Secondary2 = Secondary2.replace(',', '-')
    Weight = general_data[4].decode("utf-8") 
    Height = general_data[5].decode("utf-8")
    Height2 = int(''.join(filter(str.isdigit, Height)))
    Height2 = str(Height2)
    Height2 = Height2[:1]+'.'+Height2[1:]
    Age = general_data[6].decode("utf-8") 
    Born = general_data[7].decode("utf-8") 
    span3 = soup.find('div', class_='player-stat-tables-right')

    all_player_quirk_data.append([Player, Link, Overall, Team])
    quirks = soup.find('div', class_='quirk-wrapper')              
    for length in quirks.find_all('div', class_='quirk-item'):
        for quirk in length.find_all("strong"):
            all_player_quirk_data.append(quirk.contents)
        for quirkdesc in length.find_all('br'):
            all_player_quirk_data.append(quirkdesc.next_sibling.strip())            


    for line in all_player_quirk_data:
        if line not in quirk_data_final:
            quirk_data_final.append(line)

    if Position in ('SP','RP','CP'):
        attributes = span2.find_all('div', class_='player-attr-number')
        for each in attributes:
            stats_data.append(each.text.strip().encode('utf-8'))  
        for length in span3.find_all("strong"):
            pitch_speeds.append(length.next_sibling.strip())
            pitching_data.append(length.contents)
        Pitch_1 = str(pitching_data[0])
        Pitch_2 = str(pitching_data[1])
        Pitch_3 = str(pitching_data[2])
        try:
            Pitch_4 = str(pitching_data[3])
        except IndexError:
            Pitch_4 = 'null'
        try:
            Pitch_5 = str(pitching_data[4])
        except IndexError:
            Pitch_5 = 'null'
        Pitch_1_Speed = str(pitch_speeds[0])
        Pitch_2_Speed = str(pitch_speeds[1])
        Pitch_3_Speed = str(pitch_speeds[2]) 
        try:
            Pitch_4_Speed = str(pitch_speeds[3])
        except IndexError:
            Pitch_4_Speed = 'null'
        try:
            Pitch_5_Speed = str(pitch_speeds[4])
        except IndexError:
            Pitch_5_Speed = 'null'
        Pitch_1 = Pitch_1.translate({ord(i): None for i in '[]'})
        Pitch_2 = Pitch_2.translate({ord(i): None for i in '[]'})
        Pitch_3 = Pitch_3.translate({ord(i): None for i in '[]'})
        Pitch_4 = Pitch_4.translate({ord(i): None for i in '[]'})
        Pitch_5 = Pitch_5.translate({ord(i): None for i in '[]'})
        Pitch_1_Speed = Pitch_1_Speed.translate({ord(i): None for i in '(),'})
        Pitch_2_Speed = Pitch_2_Speed.translate({ord(i): None for i in '(),'})
        Pitch_3_Speed = Pitch_3_Speed.translate({ord(i): None for i in '(),'})
        Pitch_4_Speed = Pitch_4_Speed.translate({ord(i): None for i in '(),'})
        Pitch_5_Speed = Pitch_5_Speed.translate({ord(i): None for i in '(),'})
        Stamina = stats_data[0].decode("utf-8")
        Hper9 =stats_data[1].decode("utf-8")
        Kper9 =stats_data[2].decode("utf-8")
        BBper9 =stats_data[3].decode("utf-8")
        HRper9 =stats_data[4].decode("utf-8")
        Clutch_P =stats_data[5].decode("utf-8")
        Control =stats_data[6].decode("utf-8")
        Velocity =stats_data[7].decode("utf-8")
        Break =stats_data[8].decode("utf-8")
        Contact_Right =stats_data[9].decode("utf-8")
        Contact_Left =stats_data[10].decode("utf-8")
        Power_Right =stats_data[11].decode("utf-8")
        Power_Left =stats_data[12].decode("utf-8")
        Vision =stats_data[13].decode("utf-8")
        Discipline =stats_data[14].decode("utf-8")
        Clutch_H =stats_data[15].decode("utf-8")
        Bunt =stats_data[16].decode("utf-8")
        Drag_Bunt =stats_data[17].decode("utf-8")
        Durability =stats_data[18].decode("utf-8")
        Fielding =stats_data[19].decode("utf-8")
        Arm_Strength =stats_data[20].decode("utf-8")
        Arm_Accuracy =stats_data[21].decode("utf-8")
        Reaction =stats_data[22].decode("utf-8")
        Speed =stats_data[23].decode("utf-8")
        Steal =stats_data[24].decode("utf-8")
        Baserunning_Aggressiveness =stats_data[25].decode("utf-8")
        all_player_data_P.append([Player, Link, Overall, Team, Position, Number, Bats, Throws, Secondary2, Weight, Height2, Age, Born, 
        Pitch_1,
        Pitch_1_Speed,
        Pitch_2,
        Pitch_2_Speed,
        Pitch_3,
        Pitch_3_Speed,
        Pitch_4,
        Pitch_4_Speed,
        Pitch_5,        
        Pitch_5_Speed,
        Stamina,
        Hper9,
        Kper9,
        BBper9,
        HRper9,
        Clutch_P,
        Control,
        Velocity,
        Break,
        Contact_Right,
        Contact_Left,
        Power_Right,
        Power_Left,
        Vision,
        Discipline,
        Clutch_H,
        Bunt,
        Drag_Bunt,
        Durability,
        Fielding,
        Arm_Strength,
        Arm_Accuracy,
        Reaction,
        Speed,
        Steal,
        Baserunning_Aggressiveness])
        print('Added: '+Player)
    else:
        attributes = span2.find_all('div', class_='player-attr-number')
        for each in attributes:
            stats_data.append(each.text.strip().encode('utf-8'))
        Contact_Right =stats_data[0].decode("utf-8")
        Contact_Left =stats_data[1].decode("utf-8")
        Power_Right =stats_data[2].decode("utf-8")
        Power_Left =stats_data[3].decode("utf-8")
        Vision =stats_data[4].decode("utf-8")
        Discipline =stats_data[5].decode("utf-8")
        Clutch_H =stats_data[6].decode("utf-8")
        Bunt =stats_data[7].decode("utf-8")
        Drag_Bunt =stats_data[8].decode("utf-8")
        Durability =stats_data[9].decode("utf-8")
        Fielding =stats_data[10].decode("utf-8")
        Arm_Strength =stats_data[11].decode("utf-8")
        Arm_Accuracy =stats_data[12].decode("utf-8")
        Reaction =stats_data[13].decode("utf-8")
        if Position == 'C' or (Secondary in ('C') and Secondary not in 'CF'):
            Blocking = stats_data[14].decode("utf-8")
            Speed =stats_data[15].decode("utf-8")
            Steal =stats_data[16].decode("utf-8")
            Baserunning_Aggressiveness =stats_data[17].decode("utf-8")
        else:
            Blocking = ''
            Speed =stats_data[14].decode("utf-8")
            Steal =stats_data[15].decode("utf-8")
            Baserunning_Aggressiveness =stats_data[16].decode("utf-8")
        all_player_data_NoP.append([Player, Link, Overall, Team, Position, Number, Bats, Throws, Secondary2, Weight, Height2, Age, Born,    
        Contact_Right,
        Contact_Left,
        Power_Right,
        Power_Left,
        Vision,
        Discipline,
        Clutch_H,
        Bunt,
        Drag_Bunt,
        Durability,
        Fielding,
        Arm_Strength,
        Arm_Accuracy,
        Reaction,
        Blocking, 
        Speed,
        Steal,
        Baserunning_Aggressiveness])
        print('Added: '+Player)
    return;

data = []
teams = 28#-1

while teams < 30:
    if teams == -1:
        page_count_max = 36
    else:
        page_count_max = 7
    page = 1
    while True:        
        urltemplate = "https://mlb19.theshownation.com/inventory?page={page}&type=players&optional_id={team}"
        url = urltemplate.format(page=page, team=teams)
        driver.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "lxml")
        spans = soup.find_all('div', class_='flex-grid-quad-box')
        for span in spans:   
            Link = 'https://mlb19.theshownation.com'+span.a['href']
            data.append(Link)
        page += 1
        print (f'Working: Team- {teams} Page- {page}')
        if page > page_count_max:
            break        
    teams +=1    

for index in data:
    pull_player(url2 = index) 

print(quirk_data_final)
```

Comment: Well, are we supposed to guess what your database table definition looks like? What about the code to assemble the list of values? Please edit the question and post the relevant code.

Comment: Answering this question doesn't require my table definitions or the code to assemble the list of values - it's a list in python, same as any other.  I gave the definitions for the columns in question - the others I can manage just fine.  However, I'll update my question with my code.

Comment: Note that SQL syntax doesn't require column names for an `insert` statement if a value is provided in the `values` list for every column in the table. I'm sure you can manage from here.

Comment: So that's the issue at hand - if a player only has 5 perks then I have nothing for the other 10 where null or nothing should be inserted.  So I either need to list the column names dynamically based on the value list OR need to make it insert null for any value that has no data.  But I just realized I can do that outside of the insert statement, filling all the extra columns with null.  Thanks!

Comment: Consider database normalization and use three tables: *Players*, *Teams*, and *Quirks* where the last maintains data in long format with **one** quirk and **one** description column.

Comment: @Parfait - you're not wrong, that would be the proper way to do it and would make the programming MUCH easier.  The issue is that I'm distributing this database to a bunch of people who don't know how to use SQL and wouldn't be able to put together a join to pull player, stats and quirks from 3 different tables.

Comment: Just create a view that replicates your intended table here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, consider a long, normalized table and avoid the named columns of numbered *Quirks*. For distribution among your users, create a view (i.e., saved `SELECT` query) for your reporting needs.

**SQLite** *(ideally Player and its characteristics are not repeated but stored in a related primary table)*

```sql
CREATE TABLE "Quirks" (
   "ID" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
   "Player" TEXT, 
   "Link" TEXT, 
   "Overall" INTEGER, 
   "Team" TEXT, 
   "Quirk_Num" INTEGER,
   "Quirk" TEXT, 
   "Description" TEXT
);

-- CONDITIONAL AGGREGATION TO REPLICATE ORIGINAL TABLE SETUP
CREATE VIEW Quirk_View AS

    SELECT Player, Link, Overall, Team,
           MAX(CASE WHEN Quirk_Num = 1 THEN Quirk ELSE NULL END) AS [Quirk 1],
           MAX(CASE WHEN Quirk_Num = 1 THEN Description ELSE NULL END) AS [Quirk 1 Description],
           MAX(CASE WHEN Quirk_Num = 2 THEN Quirk ELSE NULL END) AS [Quirk 2],
           MAX(CASE WHEN Quirk_Num = 2 THEN Description ELSE NULL END) AS [Quirk 2 Description],
           MAX(CASE WHEN Quirk_Num = 3 THEN Quirk ELSE NULL END) AS [Quirk 3],
           MAX(CASE WHEN Quirk_Num = 3 THEN Description ELSE NULL END) AS [Quirk 3 Description],
           ...
    FROM Quirks
    GROUP BY Player, Link, Overall, Team;
```

**HTML** *(assumed quirks section to scrape)*

```html
...
<div class="quirk-wrapper">
    <div class_='quirk-item'>
        <strong>Quirk 1</strong>
        <br/>Quick 1 Description
    </div>
    <div class_='quirk-item'>
        <strong>Quirk 2</strong>
        <br/>Quick 2 Description
    </div>
    <div class_='quirk-item'>
        <strong>Quirk 3</strong>
        <br/>Quick 3 Description
    </div>
    ...
</div>
...
```

**Python**

```py
import sqlite3
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
...

soup = ... ;  conn = ...; cur = ...

### WEB SCRAPE
all_player_quirk_data = []

quirks = soup.find('div', class_='quirk-wrapper')   

# USING enumerate() FOR ITERATOR NUMBER
for i, item in enumerate(quirks.find_all('div', class_='quirk-item')):
    Quirk = None; Desc = None

    if item.find("strong") is not None:
        Quirk = item.find("strong").contents
    if item.find("br") is not None:
        Desc = item.find('br').next_sibling.strip()

    all_player_quirk_data.append([Player, Link, Overall, Team, i, Quirk, Desc])

### DATABASE APPEND
sql = """INSERT INTO Quirks (Player, Link, Overall, Team, Quirk_Num, Quirk, Description)
         VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
      """ 
cur.executemany(sql, all_player_quirk_data)
conn.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way in python is to maintain three lists which I  normally call `columns`, `placeholders` and `bind_values`.  You can then insert comma delimited versions of the columns and placeholders into the sql string and use it with the corresponding bind values.

```
COMMA = ',' 
columns = list()
placeholders = list()
bind_values = list()

for each atttribute in attributes:
    columns.append( attribute.name ) 
    placeholders.append('?')
    bind_values.append( attribute.value) 

 
sql = 'INSERT INTO Mytable ({COMMA.join(columns)} ) VALUES( {COMMA.join( placeholders)} ; ' 
cursor = conn.execute( sql , bind_values )
```

I find  this technique  quite useful for user driven queries where I can add a column constraints to the WHERE clause while still using bind variables to prevent SQL injection attacks all based on which form fields are completed by the user.